# how to combine in LWUIT?

Tags: lwuit

I have used this code for combine `textFiled.PASSWORD` with  `TextField.NUMERIC`

```
txtpwd.setConstraint(TextField.PASSWORD | TextField.NUMERIC);
```

When I run in Emulator i can type string .but i just typed NUMERIC .

I go to this link and find to combine constraints !!!

[How to combine constraints](http://www.eli.sdsu.edu/courses/fall04/cs683/j2me/docs/api/midp/javax/microedition/lcdui/TextField.html#NUMERIC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. The link that you have put is a lcdui API, be carefull about it.

This is the `TextField` API that you need

http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/TextField.html

Ok, seeing this http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/TextArea.html#setConstraint(int)

I think that you must use this line:

```
textField.setConstraint(TextField.NUMERIC | TextField.PASSWORD);
```

just the opposite.